# Trying to install Ubuntu 12.10 on iBook G4 from a USB key

Tags: live-usb, usb-drive, mac

I want to install Ubuntu on my iBook G4, but I cannot use liveCD because a CD is stuck in the drive lol... It's been a year or so. I've tried everything excepted opening it up but yeah... I've thought the only good alternative would be to use a bootable USB thumb drive.

So as far as I understand, the Mac cannot boot from an .iso ->
I converted the iso into an .img following these instructions:

[How to install Ubuntu on MacBook using USB Stick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick) from help.ubuntu.com

Unfortunatly, later after "burning" the .img on the drive, I immediatly get an error message telling me that: "You have inserted a disk containing volumes that Mac OS X can't read.

After what if I boot and hold the alt button to get to boot menu, I see only my hardrive and not my USB key. But I followed all of the instructions...

Does anyon have an idea about the issue?

Answer (score 1):

find another mac (any type) and a FireWire (male to male) and put the ios image on the computer yout not installing it on and pressing "T" during startup until you see a FireWire symbol, then bott the computer you want to install vit on and press command+option (option boot) then select the computer which will dhow up as whatever thats computers hard drives name is then find the ios and boot it off there.

Or you could put it on a firewire hard drive and do that. hope that helped you